Oven 3 Wire Question
I just removed a 46-year-old GE single oven. The house wiring to the old oven consists of 2 hots and a bare ground wire in Romex sheathing (no neutral wire). It is a dedicated circuit. The house was built in 1978. The 46-year-old oven has 4 wires. The white neutral wire from the oven and the bare ground wire from the oven were clamped together and attached to the bare ground wire from the house source. The nameplate on the oven says "120/240 volts". This oven, wired this way, has operated without incident for 46 years. I have looked at the installation instructions for new GE, Frigidaire, and Whirlpool ovens. They all have 3-house-wire installation instructions based on 2 hots and a neutral, not 2 hots and a ground. Is it code compliant for me to wire a new oven in the same manner that this old oven was wired? Is it safe?

Can you post a photo of your situation? I suspect your installation may not be legal or legally retrofittable...

The bare ground was used as the neutral for a NEMA 10 type circuit.  They were ban in 96 to be installed as being unsafe/killing people, but grandfather in if already installed.
It is highly recommended to use the more safe NEMA 14 circuits(two hots, neutral, and a ground) instead of NEMA 10 circuits.

Your cable is likely a Type SE "Service Entrance" cable that the bare wire is a designated neutral, and is recognized by the NEC as acceptable to ground via the bare neutral (called the grounded conductor in the NEC). See note (4) below.

250.140(B) Grounded Conductor Connections For existing branch-circuit installations only, if an equipment grounding conductor
is not present in the outlet or junction box the frame of the
appliance shall be permitted to be connected to the grounded conductor
if all the conditions in the following list items (1), (2), and (3)
are met and the grounded conductor complies with either list item (4)
or (5):
(1)The supply circuit is 120/240-volt, single-phase, 3-wire; or
208Y/120-volt derived from a 3-phase, 4-wire, wye connected system.
(2)The grounded conductor is not smaller than 10 AWG copper or 8 AWG
aluminum or copper-clad aluminum. (3)Grounding contacts of receptacles
furnished as part of the equipment are bonded to the equipment.
(4)The grounded conductor is insulated, or the grounded conductor is
uninsulated and part of a Type SE service-entrance cable and the
branch circuit originates at the service equipment.
(5)The grounded conductor is part of a Type SE service-entrance cable
that originates in equipment other than a service. The grounded
conductor shall be insulated or field covered within the supply
enclosure with listed insulating material, such as tape or sleeving to
prevent contact of the uninsulated conductor with any normally
noncurrent-carrying metal parts.


Thank you. How can I determine if my cable is a Type SE cable? It looks like Romex to me.

While I agree SE would make things more likely to be legitimate, I am with OP on "looks like Romex"

From a common sense perspective, why is a bare copper wire that's part of a Type SE cable code-compliant, and a bare copper wire that's part of a Romex cable non-compliant? Are they not equally hazardous?

@RichB  Yes.  This is definitely not safe.  Any number of things can go wrong.  It's not that dangerous.  People have used these setups for decades without problem.  When it does fail though, it can be fatal.  It's probably code compliant because it's grandfathered so that people don't have to replace a working (if unsafe) installation.  You are not legally required to update this, but people here recommend that you do so.

Current takes all paths. Since the neutral wire from the oven is crimped to the bare ground wire that is screwed onto the oven chassis, why wouldn't the chassis be electrified when the oven is turned on?

@RichB The chassis does become a reference point in the current path of a series circuit, but with the effective impedance of about 10Ω for the dryer, and resistance of 0.1Ω per 100 ft of #10 (to panel) the  frame voltage to ground is less than 2.5v, normally not enough to penetrate dry skin. When a body does complete a parallel  current path the resistance of a human body is so much higher that the wire that most of the current flows on the wire .
